# Hiding <p> tag after <span>

Tags: css

I have some code I'm attempting to modify with css. I don't have access to the source code so I need to override some settings.

Basically what I'm trying to do is hide an element that appears immediately after another. As you can see below the items are the same level of the DOM but I want to hide the `<p>` tag. I've tried `::after` but it doesn't seem to do what I want. I also didn't see this thread anywhere else but I apologize if I missed it. Any help would be wonderful.

For instance:

```
<span class='span'>Text</span>
<p class='paragraph'>More Text</p>
```

I want to keep the `<span>` but display:none the `<p>`